# DocumentItem (IMessage) loses attachment after opening

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

In our MAPI message store provider, we present both email and non-outlook items (office documents etc). Technically, we provide these documents as an IMessage object with a single attachment and a specific `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` (e.g. *IPM.Document.txtfile*) . Outlook then considers this object to be a `DocumentItem`, not a `MailItem`.

As you can see in the screenshot below, this works fine. Previewer works as expected, double clicking the item will open the item in the appropriate application (e.g. *Notepad*).

[image: Before opening - preview works fine]

However, after the item has been opened, *once the external application closes*, something goes amiss. The preview breaks, and the item can not be opened again until another item is selected first.

[image: After opening - preview breaks, opening breaks]

According to Outlook Spy, our `IMessage` object is still perfectly fine. It is the OOM `DocumentItem` wrapper **that is now somehow missing it's attachment**:

[image: DocumentItem Missing attachment]

What could be causing this behavior? Is there a refresh we are missing? Is the Outlook item presenting an old IMessage object that has gone corrupt? We've spend quite a bit of research on this topic already, all pointers are welcome!

**[EDIT 1]**

Here is Outlook spy stating our `IMessage` object is still ok:

[image: IMessage still fine]

**[EDIT 2]**

As long as the external application doesn't close, everything is fine. I can open the document as many times as I want, but as soon as I close a single instance of the external viewer the Outlook item gets "corrupted".

Comment: What does IMessage | GetAttachmentTable show? Can you step through your code to see Outlook calls when you try to reopen the item?

Comment: IMessage | GetAttachmentTable is fine, I'll update the answer in a minute. When doubleclicking the item _after_ "the attachment has disappeared", Outlook doesn't talk to our message store provider much (a single compareEntryIDs / getIDsFromNames... no calls to our IMessage occur.

Comment: What names/ids does Outlook request when it calls GetIDsFromNames?

Comment: Will post in the morning when I have access to the system. Question in return: why do you keep focusing on the re-opening of the item, and not on the (huge amount of) MAPI requests happening when we close the external application? Because _that_ seems to me when the Outlook wrapper starts malfunctioning? Are you suspecting something?

Comment: You did not mention any MAPI requests when the external app closes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to imply "lots of stuff happening" with the italic *once the external application closes*. Outlook monitors the attachment tempfile when you open a DocumentItem (or the external process, I'm not sure), and does a _lot_ when you close it. That's where all the MAPI calls come streaming in. Too much info to post, really. I'll see if I can write it up an in executive summary.

Comment: It [this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865392.aspx) related?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know... I would open a support case with MS if nothing else helps...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to think about it. I'm just confused by the fact that "something" cleans out the attachment table. Also, I really wish there still was a complete MAPI store sample available for reference purposes. The wrapped store sample is utterly useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be really simple,

> The **PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS** property needs to include **MSGFLAG_HASATTACH**

Adding this flag immediately fixed the issue, and makes perfect sense. It's just that the resulting behavior of Outlook (working at first access, then breaking) threw us off.